# WPF window becomes black for 0.5s after restoring if visual effects for minimize/maximize are disabled

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

When visual effects for minimizing/maximizing of windows are disabled in Control Panel, WPF window becomes black for a fraction of second upon restoring from minimized state.

Some of our users find it annoying and ask me to find a solution. May be someone encountered this and know a way to resolve it?

My window is heavily styled, I'm using PNG images to skin it.

Comment: Isn't that "disable visual effects for min/max" meant to do that blackening? Tell the users to put that thing on if they hate that black flickering. This just sounds like "My users have removed tires from car. Now they want to drive it, but it doesn't have tires".

Comment: Have you tried to set `AllowsTransparency` to true?

Comment: They are seeing the unpainted window for a while.  It just takes too long to generate the render commands from the visual tree in your app, it is no longer covered up by the frame animation.  "Heavily styled" is surely the underlying problem.  Maybe [this blog post](http://mrpfister.com/journal/wpf-rendering-performance/) can help but we can't help you arrive at the right solution, best to leave it to somebody else to say `No!!!`

Comment: Mino, other apps do not have this issue (non-WPF). cdmnk, it requires WindowStyle = None to set AllowsTransparency = true. Hans Passant, but why does it not happen if the visual effects for minimizing/maximizing are enabled?